# Use same layout in two activities, called from two different fragments within a view pager, not working?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm trying to use the same layout file in two different activities, as many others have asked for help on here.
However I'm calling the activities from within a view pager in two different fragments, which is where I think the problem is occurring.

My problem is that when I'm running the application, the layout will stick to look like the activity which was first initiated in the view pager. It's possible to see both versions of the layout, depending on which path is taken when first opening the application.

Main Activity, which include the viewpager

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupprotFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewByID(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionPAgerAdapter);
    TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
}
```

View pager class

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment frag;
    switch(position) {
        case 0: {
            frag = new Fragment 1();
            ...
            frag.setArguments(args);
            break;}
         ...            
         case 2: {
            frag = new Fragment 3();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();                
            frag.setArguments(args)
            break;}
         case 3: {
            frag = new Fragment 4();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            frag.setArguments(args);
            break;}
        }
    return frag;
}

public int getCount() { return 4; }
```

Fragment 3

```
public View onCreateView(...) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getArray());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ((RecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final int position, View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity1.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    ]);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewByID(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManger(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    return rootView;
}
```

Fragment 4 (Same layout as Fragment 3, same code except intent call)

```
public View onCreateView(...) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getArray());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ((RecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final int position, View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    ]);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewByID(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManger(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    return rootView;
}
```

Activity 1

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(svaedInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityLayout);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Activity 1 text");

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Activity 2

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(svaedInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityLayout);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Activity 2 text");

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

The activity 1 layout-version will be the one used if I either scroll through the view pager or I click the third tab, while the activity 2 layout-version can be seen if clicking on fourth tab before third tab have been loaded.

So to summon up the question: How do I make the two activities show two different versions of the same xml-layout?

**#EDIT:** After debugging as @vanguard told me, I begin to believe it's because the onItemClick-method in the fragments are getting overriden by each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to be within the RecyclerViewAdapter, as I had made the clickListener static. This meant that the fragment which called last, was the one which MyClickListener-method was used.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing the same xml layout should work fine so that is likely not your problem here. I'm assuming you're not hitting the correct path somehow.

I'd recommend breakpointing your code to determine whether Activity1 or Activity2 is being started.

Comment: Not the sharpest in debugging but did my best and got these results:
1) Fragment 3 is being called if scrolling to fragment 2, and if scrolling to fragment 3 fragment 4 is called. - Shows me Activity 2

2) Clicking directly on tab 3 (fragment 3) it will call fragment 4, and then fragment 3. - Shows activity 1.

3) Clicking directly on tab 4 (fragment 4) will call fragment 3, and then fragment 4 - Shows activity 2.